# What doe these three seals mean?

Tags: seal

I just inherited this painting and wanted to know what it says. Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!
[image]

[1[[image: ]2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksLrN.jpg

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDjjJ.jpg)
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: the left characters of the last seal are “審定”, roughly “examine & approved”; for others, any clearer photos?

Comment: Just added some more pictures! Any other tips for identifying this painting? Thank you so much for all your help :)

Comment: the headgear looks like korean style “男紗帽”